# Api Level 24 not able to record another person's voice. There is no issue in permissions

Tags: java, android

api but after insall api 24 android version not able to record other person voice My call recorder app working perfect below 24 api but after insall Api Android 24 version not able to record other person. I check all audiosource one by one.

```
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        fileName = FileHelper.getFilename(phoneNumber);
        recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
```

Comment: In what way is it now "not able to record" someone else's voice? Are you getting a specific error message? Does your app hang? Does it record eldritch blasphemies from beyond time instead?

Comment: @Zahid Ali - Any update on this as I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In API level 23+ you are required to ask for permissions at run time as opposed to install time. Have you made this check before you attempt to record sound?

Please see the following doc for help on this: [Request permissions at runtime appropriately (in Android 6.0+)](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/runtime-permissions)

Comment: I add all permissions at runtime in main activity